# Dart code for activate how create login action

Tags: android, ios, xml, flutter, dart

Dart code for activate  how create login  action

How do I create a login UI in Flutter?
Then we create a Stateful widget.
Set Scaffold's AppBar property as follows to make a heading for our application.
For this UI, all widgets are placed inside the Column widget, into the Scaffold body. ...
Here, the flutter-logo. ...
Then, for Username or Email and Password use the TextField widget

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.